# Welch's overlapped method for amplitude by frequency estimation

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density, spectrum-estimation

pwelch  is a useful matlab function for computing real/magnitudes for power using WOSA method, but I'd like to apply the same thinking in order to output complex pairs for amplitude (not power) spectra.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or if there is an existing script that I might be able to modify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found this:
[Implementing Welch's method for Power Spectral Density](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30762/implementing-welchs-method-for-power-spectral-density)

That seems to answer the question. However, the author encountered a problem, which I believe may be addressed by modifying the code that was identified as problematic in the thread by:

dataA(istart:iend,j) = data1(istart:iend,j).*window;
dataB(istart:iend,j) = data2(istart:iend,j).*window;